# Audio capture in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I am developing an audio capture application. How to capture audio on Mac OS X using 8 kHz sampling rate with single chanel using Audio Unit API ?

This is the code I have tried.

```
    Component                   component;
ComponentDescription        description;
OSStatus    err = noErr;
UInt32  param;
AURenderCallbackStruct  callback;

description.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
description.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput;
description.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
description.componentFlags = 0;
description.componentFlagsMask = 0;
if(component = FindNextComponent(NULL, &description))
{
    err = OpenAComponent(component, &fAudioUnit);
    if(err != noErr)
    {
        fAudioUnit = NULL;
        return err;
    }
}
param = 1;
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(fAudioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &param, sizeof(UInt32));
if(err == noErr)
{
    param = 0;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(fAudioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &param, sizeof(UInt32));
}
param = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
err = AudioHardwareGetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice, &param, &fInputDeviceID);
if(err != noErr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to get default input device\n");
    return err;
}
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(fAudioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &fInputDeviceID, sizeof(AudioDeviceID));
if(err != noErr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to set AU input device\n");
    return err;
}
callback.inputProc = AudioInputProc; 
callback.inputProcRefCon = NULL;
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(fAudioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &callback, sizeof(AURenderCallbackStruct));
param = sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);
err = AudioUnitGetProperty(fAudioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &fDeviceFormat, &param);
if(err != noErr)
{
    printf("failed to get input device ASBD\n");
    return err;
}
fDeviceFormat.mSampleRate = 8000.0;
fDeviceFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
fDeviceFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
fDeviceFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
fDeviceFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(fAudioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &fDeviceFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));
if(err != noErr)
{
    printf( "failed to set input device ASBD= %4.4s\n",(char *)&err);
    if(err == kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported)
    {
        printf("kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported\n");
    }
    return err;
}
err = AudioUnitGetProperty(fAudioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &fDeviceFormat, &param);
if(err != noErr)
{
    printf( "failed to get input device ASBD\n");
    return err;
}   
param = sizeof(UInt32);
err = AudioUnitGetProperty(fAudioUnit, kAudioDevicePropertyBufferFrameSize, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &fAudioSamples, &param);
if(err != noErr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to get audio sample size\n");
    return err;
}
err = AudioUnitInitialize(fAudioUnit);
if(err != noErr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize AU\n");
    return err;
}
```

Here I am unable to change the sample rate and bit per samples from 32 to 16. Please any one help me to do this.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Do you want to record audio from the microphone or capture audio from another app?

Comment: I need to capture audio from microphone. Thanks for your fast response.

Answer (score 2):

Capture with supported format and convert it to **8000 kHz,**

**With the above code** `AudioUnitSetProperty` **is going to be failed.**

You need to create audio converter using `AudioConvertNew` and convert your buffer to desired format using `AudioConverterConvertBuffer`.

Comment: Did you mean AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer instead of AudioConverterConvertBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [source code for SoundFlower](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/). That might help to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I had to modify sand box permissions. Check if your application is sand boxed, you have access to the microphone.